Pylint unnecessary pass statement for abstract method
I have an abstract method which just includes a pass statement, as the method implementation is in another class that inherits from this abstract class. Here is the method:
@abstractmethod
def parse_sun_times(self, times_as_strings: Dict[str, str]) -> SunTimes:
    """
    Parses a dictionary of time strings into a SunTimes object.

    Args:
        times_as_strings (Dict[str, str]): A dictionary containing time strings as values and
        sun phases as keys

    Returns:
        SunTimes: An object representing parsed sunrise, sunset, and twilight times.
    """
    pass

Pylint is giving the warning "unnecessary pass statement". Is there some way I can signify to pylint that this is an abstract method, or do I just have to disable the warning manually?

Does the same error occur if you use ... instead of pass?

Yes, I get the unnecessary ellipses constant warning

This would seem to indicate that you can just remove it... have you tried that?

Yes that makes the code work, but PEP 3119 says its best practice to include the pass. This is why I thought I would somehow be able to signal to pylint that it's an abstract class

Is it even valid Python syntax without pass?

The docs appear to assume you already have a docstring as the first element after the signature (which would explain the recommendation to simply remove it, definition would still be syntactically complete)

And I presume that the pylint warning only comes when you have that docstring. I can't believe it would recommend invalid syntax.

Yes, this is correct! Removing the docstring removed the warning, and vice versa with the pass statement!

As mentioned in Mathias' comment, because there is a docstring as the first element after the signature, the definition is syntactically complete without the need for a pass statement. To remove the warning, either remove the docstring or the pass statement, as it is unnecessary to include both.
